# Custom implementation of MSP

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I do want to implement my own identity version of MSP. I mean instead of default  PKI based Identity validation, signature verification, I would like to do that using token based identity validation and signature verification.

Please let me know if it is possible to override the default certificate based authentication/validation with custom authentication and validation in MSP.

Regards,
vdr

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to support multiple types of MSPs.  The design is to support multiple types of identities (i.e. MSP types) concurrently, not just one at a time.  This means that one organization may use the default X509-based type of identities, another organization may use the idemix (short for "Identity Mixer") type of identities, and another organization may use yet another type.  These three organizations can transact on a single channel.

An idemix MSP type is currently being implemented which supports advanced crypto based on zero-knowledge proof.  You can look at fabric/msp/idemixmsp.go in the master branch to get a feel for how to implement your own MSP type.  But before starting, I would encourage you to see if idemix will meet your needs.  You could also ask more specific questions on the #fabric-crypto rocket chat channel if you want to learn more about idemix.